# ImapX | vb.net - Attachments colection is empty even id the mail actually have attachments

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, imapx

I'm trying to download and safe the attachments form an email message, but the message come with the Attachments collection empty and it doesn't make any sense.
Everything else is working properly though. I can read emails and see all the properties.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend contacting ImapX about it. Though, after some quick recon, they don't look very fast acting.

https://github.com/azanov/imapx/issues

I've had this issue before with old fashioned mapi interfaces, and often the mapi 'server' doesn't give the attachment information in a way that mapi understands, so it reports 0 attachments. Thunderbird by mozilla does that. And outlook 2016 ruins the attachment name before giving it to you, so you never know what it was really called.